# Reducer takes more time after 92%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a bulk load job using HFileOutputFormat to load a HBase table.  My mapper completes within 2-3 mins and then the reducer(PutSortReducer invoked by HFileOutputFomat) completes till 92% in the next 2 mins, but takes around 9 mins to complete the remaining 8%

Totally 10 reduce tasks are spawned in my job, of which always 8 or 9 tasks completes within 2-3 mins and the remaining one or two tasks take then 9 mins.  And these one or two last tasks are usually the ones restarted in place of the failed tasks.  The logs don't show any evident errors as the reason of the failed tasks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441090/bulk-data-loading-using-hfileoutputformat-is-not-optimally-performing-as-expecte

Comment: Do the 2 reducer tasks fail after 10 minutes (the default timeout period if the reducer doesn't report progress). Also for the reducers that succeeded, did they actually process and input records or are all the records being sent to these two reducers?

Comment: Yes, the all the reducers do complete, though the last 1 or 2 are taking more time and yes, functionally everything is working fine

Comment: but how do i find if the initial 8 reduces tasks actually processed the data? I could the bytes written count in these tasks, this means they processed the data, right?